# Mac OS: Print the Access Control List (ACL) in C

Tags: c, macos, permissions, acl

I want to print ACL text like the on in "ls" command, but I have no idea how to get these permissions, any lead?

[image]

Comment: At the command-line, type “man acl” to see the manual page for the ACL routines. Somebody more conversant than I with them might answer further, but that could get you started. There are several routines to get ACLs from file system objects and a routine named `acl_to_text` that seems like it might be very helpful in generating the text to describe ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for getting the file (POSIX) ACL in C code, and printing them:

```
const char *path = "/path/to/file";
acl_t acl = acl_get_link_np (path, ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED);
if (acl == NULL) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
} else {
    const char *desc = acl_to_text (acl, NULL);
    printf("%s\n", desc);
    acl_free ((void*)desc);
}
acl_free (acl);
```

The group will be shown as a UUID, not as a name such as "everyone", though.

If you want to parse the ACL yourself instead of getting the default printout, type `man acl` in Terminal.